# Duplicating random content in certain div, and display its mirrored copy

Tags: javascript, jquery

Yes, that title may seem strange, but here is my problem. I've got a div `.experiment` inside that div I have span tags which randomly change their colour. Usually if I wanted to create a duplicate I would have just copied markup, however if I do this in this case all duplicated spans inside the div will remain random, therefore be different from original ones. Is there a way to actually duplicate a div?

EDIT: I tried to figure it out with a `.clone();` of jQUery, but had no success in a nutshell, I have following markup:

```
<div id="post-1">
...
<div class="eq">
        <span class="bar-1"></span>
        <span class="bar-1"></span>
        <span class="bar-1"></span>
        <span class="bar-1"></span>
        <span class="bar-1"></span>

        <span class="bar-separator"></span>

                <!-- Duplicate .bar's go here --> 
</div>
...
</div>
```

And following JavaScript:

```
    // This is called when certain events happen
    $(".bar").each(function(i) {
          fluctuate($(this));
    });

   //This is a fluctuate function itself
   function fluctuate(bar) {
    var hgt = Math.random() * 15;
    hgt += 1;
    var t = hgt * 20;
    bar.animate({
        height: hgt * 2,
        top: hgt
    }, t, function() {
        fluctuate($(this));
    });
}
```

What happens is that each span with class="bar-1" starts randomly changing height. I need to somehow exactly duplicate all these 5 span bars and place them after span with `class="bar-separator"`. **The Difficulty** How do I copy them exactly with all random height changes associated to them? Furthermore is it possible to display them in a mirrored way e.g where first span in original data is displayed as last span in duplicated data? **Even more difficult** each span has a **class="bar-"** and than some numerical value which is dependant on what number is in `#post-[id]` div. So there are several bar instances on a page, but each group has their own number after `bar-`. So how to achieve complete duplication of only specific group of bar's?

Comment: That will depend on how the random part is implemented, and your actual markup. Could you add more details, and possibly a minimal example?

Comment: @bfavaretto added example with random heights, basically function gets  applied to all span elements with certain id making them change heights randomly.

Comment: But is the random function applied just once, or do you change the heights periodically with a timer? Also, by looking at that I see your span have IDs. If you clone them (e.g. with http://api.jquery.com/clone/), you have to remove the ids on the cloned elements, or you'll end up with duplicate ids in your document.

Comment: @bfavaretto It's applied one time, my bad the spans actually have classes, been working to much. But basically function gets applied once and then spans start randomly change height.

Comment: Okay, but from what you're telling us, we still can't be sure what's going on. I suggest first trying the jQuery clone method as Jivings suggested. If it doesn't work, set up an example on http://jsfiddle.net to reproduce the problem, so we can see exactly what's going on.

Comment: @bfavaretto tried out .copy(); had no success, I updated my question with more information, any chance you could have a look at it please.

Comment: nvm got it with clone

Comment: Glad to know! But I you didn't, the extra information you added would allow us to help this time. Happy coding!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, look at the [jQuery `clone` method](http://api.jquery.com/clone/).

Comment: I knew of this function, but I wasn't aware it can also duplicate things like random changes in height, colour etc, is that gona work?

Comment: @Ilya Yep, should work as the inline styles will be cloned as part of the element.